# Create a directory in internal storage of device in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to create a folder in the internal storage of my device, but not in the root directory, which will store the audios I've recorded using my app. I've tried using the following code to implement the same:

```
fileSys.root.getDirectory('file:///storage/sdcard/records', {create: true, exclusive: false},function(d) {
       window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL($scope.sound.file, function(fe) {
          fe.copyTo(d, filename, function(e) {
          console.log('success in copy');
          console.dir(e);
          $scope.sound.file = e.nativeURL;
          $scope.sound.path = e.fullPath;
          }, function(e) {
        console.log('error in copy');console.dir(e);
    });                 
}, function(e) {
    console.log("error in directory");
    console.dir(e);
});
}, function(e) {
    console.log("error in file");
    console.dir(e);
});
```

But an error(code = 5) is generated when I implement the above code. Can someone point out the error in the above code so the directory is created and file is copied to the specified location?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I preferred to use https://github.com/torrmal/cordova-simplefilemanagement which wraps native storage api.
Then you can do something like this:

```
 var a = new DirManager(); // Initialize a Folder manager IF does not exists
 a.create_r("NewFolder", function () {/* Notify dir creation*/ });
```